# how to debug when the server returns 200 status code?

Tags: python, web, python-requests

I use a python script which can post in a bbs automatically. After one success I failed to post again. However, I still got a 200 status code. In this situation , where to look at?

Here is response.content I have

```
'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="zh-cmn-Hans" class="">\n<head>\n    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n    <meta name="renderer" content="webkit">\n    <meta name="referrer" content="always">\n    <title>\n    \xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\xbb\x84\xe5\x8f\x91\xe8\xa8\x80\n</title>\n    \n<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://img3.doubanio.com/f/group/6ea8ab65d86f52b2762eb67be0176e969aecc1ef/css/group/group_editor.css">\n<!-- COLLECTED CSS -->\n<script src="https://img3.doubanio.com/f/shire/77323ae72a612bba8b65f845491513ff3329b1bb/js/do.js" data-cfg-autoload="false"></script>\n<script>\n_ED_ROOT = \'group-editor-root\';\n_ED_FORM = \'group-editor-form\';\n_ED_EXTRA = \'nav-top-actions\';\n_DEFAULT_EDITOR_PLACEHOLDER = \'\xe5\x86\x99\xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\xbb\x84\xe8\xaf\x9d\xe9\xa2\x98...\';\n_POST_PARAMS = {\n  siteCookie: {\n      name: \'upload_auth_token\',\n      value: \'169713688:194e107c0c53832ff77f511668c7e27beb02fd3a\'\n  }\n};\n_CDN_URL = \'//img3.doubanio.com/dae/staticng/s/group/0d7de72a8095e219c33d6aac2ee40659bd8fbcd6/js/group/editor/\';\n_DATA = {\n  user: {\n    id: \'169713688\',\n    avatar: \'https://img3.doubanio.com/icon/u169713688-2.jpg\',\n    name: \'uncharted\'\n  },\n  group: {\n    id: 521697,\n    title: "\xe8\x84\xb1\xe6\xb0\xb4\xe5\xb8\x96\xe7\xb2\xbe\xe9\x80\x89\xef\xbc\x8c\xe6\x89\x8b\xe6\x9c\xba\xe5\x85\x9a\xe7\xa6\x8f\xe5\x88\xa9\xef\xbc\x8c\xe7\x9b\xb4\xe6\x92\xad\xe5\xa4\x87\xe4\xbb\xbd",\n    cover: "https://img3.doubanio.com/view/group/sqxs/public/b5cc917404a8060.jpg",\n    url: "https://www.douban.com/group/tuoshuitie/",\n    is_member: "True" === "True"\n  }\n};\nDo.add(\'editor\', {\n  path: \'https://img3.doubanio.com/f/group/24496e4188d7b81ca1ca079b7f6e747b891f290d/js/group/editor/group_editor.js\',\n  requires: [\'https://img3.doubanio.com/f/group/aaf1129ac0f59e5d7377c448af87c8c2ad29b339/js/group/editor/libs.js\']\n});\n</script>\n\n    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://img3.doubanio.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">\n</head>\n\n<body>\n  \n    \n    <script type="text/javascript">var _body_start = new Date();</script>\n    \n<div class="nav">\n  <div class="nav-inner">\n    <div class="nav-logo">\n      <a href="">\xe8\xb1\x86\xe7\x93\xa3</a>\n    </div>\n    <h1 class="nav-label">\xe5\x86\x99\xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\xbb\x84\xe8\xaf\x9d\xe9\xa2\x98</h1>\n    <div id="nav-top-actions" class="nav-actions"></div>\n  </div>\n</div>\n\n    <div id="wrapper">\n        \n        \n<div id="content">\n    \n\n    <div class="grid-16-8 clearfix">\n        \n        \n        <div class="article">\n               \n  <div id="group-editor-root" class="group-editor">\n    <div class="group-editor-initial">\n      <p>\xe5\x8a\xa0\xe8\xbd\xbd\xe4\xb8\xad\xef\xbc\x8c\xe8\xaf\xb7\xe7\xa8\x8d\xe5\x80\x99\n    </div>\n  </div>\n  <form id="group-editor-form" method="POST"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="ck" value="E582"/></div>\n    <input type="hidden" name="topic_id" value="">\n    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="\xe6\x8e\xa8\xe8\x8d\x90\xe4\xb8\x80\xe4\xb8\xaa\xe6\x95\x85\xe4\xba\x8b\xe6\x8e\xa5\xe9\xbe\x99\xe7\xbd\x91\xe7\xab\x99">\n    <input type="hidden" name="text" value="\xe7\x8b\x97\xe5\xb0\xbe\xe7\xbb\xad\xe5\x96\xb5\xe6\x95\x85\xe4\xba\x8b\xe6\x8e\xa5\xe9\xbe\x99 http://www.gushijielong.cn \n\xe7\x8e\xa9\xe6\xb3\x95\xe4\xbb\x8b\xe7\xbb\x8d https://www.jianshu.com/p/966644c8c12a\nPS:\xe8\xaf\x97\xe4\xb8\x80\xe9\xa6\x96:\n\xe8\xbd\xac\xe5\x8f\x98\xe5\x9b\xa2\xe4\xbd\x93\xe5\xa4\x84\xe7\x90\x86\xe6\x8a\x80\xe5\xb7\xa7\xe7\x99\xbd\xe8\x89\xb2\xe6\x96\xb0\xe9\xb2\x9c\xe6\xa0\xb9\xe6\x8d\xae\xe4\xb8\x96\xe7\x95\x8c\xe6\x9d\xaf\xe4\xb8\x80\xe7\x9b\xb4\xef\xbc\x8c\xe7\x9c\x8b\xe6\x9d\xa5\xe5\x9c\xb0\xe4\xbd\x8d\xe5\x85\xb1\xe4\xba\xab\xe6\x89\x93\xe4\xba\x86\xe5\x8f\x8d\xe8\x80\x8c\xe5\xa4\xa7\xe7\x9b\x98\xe6\xaf\x8f\xe4\xb8\xaa\xe7\xad\x89\xe7\xad\x89\xe9\x9c\x80\xe8\xa6\x81\xe7\x9b\x91\xe7\xae\xa1\xe7\xad\x89\xe6\x96\xb9\xe9\x9d\xa2\xe5\x8a\xa0\xe9\x80\x9f\xe7\xba\xa7\xe5\x88\xab\xef\xbc\x8c\xe5\xbd\x93\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe4\xb9\x8b\xe5\xae\xb6\xe8\x87\xaa\xe4\xbb\x8e\xe6\x89\xa7\xe8\xa1\x8c\xe6\x97\xb6\xe9\x97\xb4\xe5\xae\x9e\xe7\x94\xa8\xe7\x94\xa8\xe9\x80\x94\xe5\xa7\x90\xe5\xa7\x90\xe5\xb0\xbd\xe5\xbf\xab\xe6\x9c\x89\xe5\x88\xa9\xe4\xba\x8e\xe9\xa9\xb1\xe5\x8a\xa8\xe5\xaf\xb9\xe8\xb1\xa1\xe4\xba\xa4\xe6\xb5\x81\xef\xbc\x8c\xe4\xbe\x9d\xe6\x97\xa7\xe7\x9b\xb8\xe5\xbd\x93\xe8\xa7\x82\xe7\x82\xb9\xe7\xab\x8b\xe5\x8d\xb3\xe4\xb8\x80\xe4\xba\x9b\xef\xbc\x8c\xe5\x86\x85\xe5\xae\xb9\xe5\x8e\xbb\xe5\xb9\xb4\xe5\xa8\xb1\xe4\xb9\x90\xe5\x85\x9a\xe5\x91\x98\xe8\xba\xab\xe5\xad\x90\xe4\xb8\x80\xe5\x89\xaf\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe5\x86\x85\xe5\xa4\x96\xe4\xb8\x80\xe5\x8f\xb0\xe5\x8f\x8b\xe6\x83\x85\xe9\x85\x92\xe5\xba\x97\xe5\x90\x88\xe4\xbd\x9c\xe5\x8f\xaf\xe6\x98\xaf\xe6\xb1\x82\xe5\x8a\xa9\xe5\xa5\xb9\xe8\xaf\xb4\xef\xbc\x8c\xe6\x9c\x89\xe7\x9a\x84\xe7\xa8\x8b\xe5\xba\xa6\xe4\xba\x8b\xe5\x8a\xa1\xe6\x83\xb3\xe8\xb1\xa1\xe4\xba\xa4\xe6\x98\x93\xef\xbc\x8c\xe4\xb8\xbb\xe6\x9c\xba\xe7\x94\xa8\xe6\x9d\xa5\xe7\x94\xb5\xe5\xbd\xb1\xe5\xbf\x83\xe7\x90\x86\xe9\xa2\x91\xe7\x8e\x87\xe5\xa5\xb3\xe5\xad\xa9\xe8\xaf\x84\xe7\xba\xa7\xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\xbb\x84\xe6\x80\x8e\xe6\xa0\xb7\xef\xbc\x8c\xe8\xa7\x89\xe5\xbe\x97\xe7\x9c\x8b\xe6\xb3\x95\xe5\xbe\x88\xe5\xbf\xab\xe5\xbe\x80\xe5\xbe\x80\xe4\xb8\x80\xe4\xb8\xaa\xe5\xad\x98\xe5\x9c\xa8\xe6\x97\xa5\xe5\xad\x90\xe6\x97\xa5\xe5\xbf\x97\xe3\x80\x82">\n  </form>\n\n        </div>\n        <div class="aside">\n                \n        </div>\n        <div class="extra">\n            \n        </div>\n    </div>\n</div>\n\n        \n    </div>\n    \n    \n\n    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://img3.doubanio.com/misc/mixed_static/1de8eb7ab613afae.js"></script>\n    \n\n\n    \n    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<!-- Google Tag Manager -->\n<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-5WP579" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>\n<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({\'gtm.start\':new Date().getTime(),event:\'gtm.js\'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!=\'dataLayer\'?\'&l=\'+l:\'\';j.async=true;j.src=\'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=\'+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,\'script\',\'dataLayer\',\'GTM-5WP579\');</script>\n<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->\n\n\n<script type="text/javascript">\nvar _paq = _paq || [];\n_paq.push([\'trackPageView\']);\n_paq.push([\'enableLinkTracking\']);\n(function() {\n    var p=((\'https:\' == document.location.protocol) ? \'https\' : \'http\'), u=p+\'://fundin.douban.com/\';\n    _paq.push([\'setTrackerUrl\', u+\'piwik\']);\n    _paq.push([\'setSiteId\', \'100001\']);\n    var d=document, g=d.createElement(\'script\'), s=d.getElementsByTagName(\'script\')[0];\n    g.type=\'text/javascript\';\n    g.defer=true;\n    g.async=true;\n    g.src=p+\'://img3.doubanio.com/dae/fundin/piwik.js\';\n    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);\n})();\n</script>\n\n<script type="text/javascript">\nvar _gaq = _gaq || [];\n_gaq.push([\'_setAccount\', \'UA-7019765-1\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_setCampNameKey\', \'dcn\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_setCampSourceKey\', \'dcs\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_setCampMediumKey\', \'dcm\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_setCampTermKey\', \'dct\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_setCampContentKey\', \'dcc\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_addOrganic\', \'baidu\', \'word\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_addOrganic\', \'soso\', \'w\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_addOrganic\', \'3721\', \'name\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_addOrganic\', \'youdao\', \'q\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_addOrganic\', \'so.360.cn\', \'q\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_addOrganic\', \'vnet\', \'kw\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_addOrganic\', \'sogou\', \'query\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_addIgnoredOrganic\', \'\xe8\xb1\x86\xe7\x93\xa3\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_addIgnoredOrganic\', \'douban\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_addIgnoredOrganic\', \'\xe8\xb1\x86\xe7\x93\xa3\xe7\xbd\x91\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_addIgnoredOrganic\', \'www.douban.com\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_setDomainName\', \'.douban.com\']);\n\n\n    _gaq.push([\'_setCustomVar\', 1, \'responsive_view_mode\', \'desktop\', 3]);\n\n_gaq.push([\'_trackPageview\']);\n_gaq.push([\'_trackPageLoadTime\']);\n    _gaq.push([\'_setVar\', \'16971\']);\n\nwindow._ga_init = function() {\n    var ga = document.createElement(\'script\');\n    ga.src = (\'https:\' == document.location.protocol ? \'https://ssl\' : \'http://www\') + \'.google-analytics.com/ga.js\';\n    ga.setAttribute(\'async\', \'true\');\n    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(ga);\n};\nif (window.addEventListener) {\n    window.addEventListener(\'load\', _ga_init, false);\n} else {\n    window.attachEvent(\'onload\', _ga_init);\n}\n</script>\n\n\n\n\n\n    <!-- daisy7c-docker-->\n\n\n  <script>_SPLITTEST=\'\'</script>\n</body>\n\n</html>\n\n\n'
```

Comment: 200 means 'OK'. The server reports it is happy with your request. It does not mean it actually is. If there's no message in the HTML code, then there is nothing to debug on client side.

Comment: @KlausD.  So there is no bug. But how to find out the reason why it failed to post?

Comment: You can compare your "success" vs "fail" responses and find what differentiates the two.  It'll give you an idea to start.  If you simply wanted to retry again when failed, scrap for the differentiating factor that indicate the POST failed and have your script run again.